# Can I move an iframe while preserving its instance/state?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If I have an iframe that's setup on a node, can I move it to another node while preserving its current state?

I must retain IE11 support for this

```js
const iframe = document.querySelector('#my-frame')

document.querySelector('#new-node').appendChild(iframe)
document.querySelector('#old-node').removeChild(iframe)
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<div id="old-node">
  Old node
  <iframe id="my-frame" src="https://example.com"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="new-node">
  New node
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost right.

However, since a DOM element can have only a single parent at a time, `.appendChild` automatically removes the element from its current parent (if it's already in the DOM).

Therefore, in your case, when you call `.removeChild`, the element is no longer the child of the old parent, and `.removeChild` throws a `DOMException`.

You have two ways:

- Move the call to `.removeChild` before `.appendChild`:

  ```
  const iframe = document.querySelector('#my-frame')

  document.querySelector('#old-node').removeChild(iframe)
  document.querySelector('#new-node').appendChild(iframe)
  ```
- But, you can even omit the call to `.removeChild`:

  ```
  const iframe = document.querySelector('#my-frame')

  document.querySelector('#new-node').appendChild(iframe)
  ```